# End of Input Error in Tellraw

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a `/tellraw` command, straight from my map:

```
 /tellraw @a [{"text":"I am a "},{"text": "DOOFUS",
 "color":"red"},{"text":".
 "},{"text":"Yes","color":"red","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/tellraw
 @a [{\"text\":\"You are \"},{\"text\":\"OFFICIALLY
 \",\"color\":\"red\"},{\"text\":\"a
 \"},{\"text\":\"DOOFUS\",\"color\":\"red\"},{\"text\":\"\nGo to the
 bottom-left of the map
 name.\"}]"}},{"text":"No","color":"green","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command",
 "value":"/tellraw @a {\"text\":\"\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\"}"}}]
```

When I run it, the chat reports `I am a DOOFUS. YesNo`, but when I click `Yes`, it says `Invalid json: End of Input at line at line 1 column 89`. Clicking `No` works.

Comment: If Yes doesn't work, then there's something wrong with your Yes command.  Try singling that out, and see what you can find.

Comment: Minecraft commands sure are confusing. Answerers: Curly bracelet counts are equal.

Answer (score 1):

When a player runs a command from a click event via `/tellraw`, they are running the command as if they have typed the command themselves into the chat. This means they are subject to standard chat limitations, such as the requirement of being OP'd and a 100-character limit.

The command you're trying to have them run exceeds that limit at 192 characters.

You will need to use a shorter command instead. If OP status is a concern, you have to use `/trigger`, which will modify the executor's score of the "trigger" type without needing to be OP'd.

#### Prerequisites

1. Adding the "trigger" objective-type, which is the only objective-type that can be used with the `/trigger` command (meaning you cannot use "dummy").

   ```
   /scoreboard objectives add CLICKED trigger
   ```
2. The commands you would run in `/tellraw`'s click event would instead be:

   ```
   /trigger CLICKED set 1
   /trigger CLICKED set 2
   ```

#### Clock commands

The following must be run in numerical order on a clock.

1. If a player activates their trigger, it becomes locked and cannot be activated again. You can constantly enable their trigger to avoid locking, though it would be up to you to determine if there's a need to keep it locked.

   ```
   /scoreboard players enable @a CLICKED
   ```
2. Run the nested `/tellraw` command if the player clicked "Yes", which set their score to 1.

   ```
   /tellraw @a[score_CLICKED_min=1,score_CLICKED=1] [{"text":"You are "},{"text":"OFFICIALLY","color":"red"},{"text":"a"},{"text":"DOOFUS","color":"red"},{"text":"\nGo to the bottom-left of the mapname."}]
   ```
3. Run the nested `/tellraw` command if the player clicked "No", which set their score to 2.

   ```
   /tellraw @a[score_CLICKED_min=2,score_CLICKED=2] {"text":"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"}
   ```
4. Reset the player's "CLICKED" score to 0.

   ```
   /scoreboard players set @a[score_CLICKED_min=1] CLICKED 0
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another (possibly easier) way:

Make the `Yes` command run a `/setblock x y z redstone_block`. The x y z are linked to two command blocks with what the `Yes` was originally connected to (except without the extra backslashes), and a `/setblock x y z air`.

Comment: Be aware that this requires the clicking player to be OP'd and does not support multi-player because you don't know who had clicked.

Comment: My map is singleplayer, so it should work. But yes, this only works in singleplayer.